# Buscar por valor de elemento en Java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de realizar un filtrado de una array por un valor que contiene uno de sus elementos. De esta manera me devuelve el primer valor de Array

```
Arrays.asList(searchHits.getHits()).stream()
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(this::parseUser)
                .get()
```

Pero ahora trato de hacer que lo que me devuelva sea el valor que tiene un valor especifico

```
Arrays.asList(searchHits.getHits()).stream()
                    .filter(b -> b.getId().equals(userId))
                    .map(this::parseUser)
```

Entiendo que el valor de b es el elemento actual que valora y de su getter valora si es igual al que busco para que me lo devuelva

Comment: Y ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿quieres recuperar todos los registros que cumplen con ese campo o solo quieres el primero)

Comment: La question es como recuperar aquello que cumpla con la concicion de equals

Comment: Entiendo que quieres los valores de de parseUser. Así recolectaras los ParseUser de los que cumplan la condicion, y lo recuperas como un `List`, tu me diras si es esto lo que quieres: `Arrays.asList(searchHits.getHits()).stream().filter(b -> b.getId().equals(userId)).map(a->a.getParseUser()).collect(Collectors.toList())`